# adding $_POST in a value='' field

Tags: php

I'm continuing to play around with PHP, and what I'd like to do is to pass variables from one form to another.

However, I can't manage to get an input field to work! I think I'm putting in the $_POST incorrectly. Help fixing this greatly appreciated

What's wrong with the code below?

```
echo "<input type='text' name='amount' value='$_POST['amount']' />";
```

Comment: `$_POST['amount']` ----> `$_POST[amount]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give it like

```
echo "<input type='text' name='amount' value='".$_POST['amount']."' />";
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use quotes to delimit the array keys inside the double-quoted string, so this:

```
echo "<input type='text' name='amount' value='$_POST[amount]' />";
```

... would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

`echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"amount\" value=\"$_POST['amount']\" />";`